# Dynamically repositioning nav menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'd like to create a nav menu for a WordPress theme that will function exactly the same as the top navigation on http://www.duarte.com/.
For example,  if you click on 'Teams', the main nav moves to the left, and the sub nav appears on the right.  Addtionally, it needs to works with the custom menus features.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `display:block; float:right;` Add this css style to the menu and the submenu.